# Update component react native status

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I am using redux and on one of my screens using function component I am not able to update the state of the screen even used in useEffect. Does anyone have any alternative?

below, part of the code used:

```
const Carrinho = ({ produtosCarrinho }) => {

    const [dadosCarrinho, setDadosCarrinho] = useState(produtosCarrinho)

    useEffect(() => {
        calcularSubTotal()

      },[produtosCarrinho]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

        </View>
    )
}

export default connect(state => ({produtosCarrinho: state.carrinhoCompra.dadosCarrinho}))(Carrinho)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're having a confusion between redux state and component local state. Here you have created a local state variable (dadosCarrinho) by calling `useState` function, you can change this value with `setDadosCarrinho`.

With redux you can update the store information by actions, actions from redux docs are:

> Actions are payloads of information that send data from your
>   application to your store. They are the only source of information for
>   the store. You send them to the store using store.dispatch().

Then you should use reducers to change application state

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to
>   actions sent to the store. Remember that actions only describe what
>   happened, but don't describe how the application's state changes.

You can dispatch actions from your component by adding a second parameter to your connect function where you specify your actions

```
export default connect(state => ({produtosCarrinho: state.carrinhoCompra.dadosCarrinho}), { /* add your actions here */ })(Carrinho)
```

[Redux docs are really very clear with basic examples](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! I used the following solution:

React.useCallback(() => {
            setDadosCarrinho(produtosCarrinho)
          }, [])

I was already receiving my redux data updated, but the status was not updated ... Is this solution used ugly or incorrect?